Jenkins active choice parameter loses <scripts> in HTML when I use Referenced parameters
def givenValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] // it works

// EVN is a Referenced parameters.
// The error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: getSelectedValues is not defined"
if ENV.equals("test"){
    givenValues = [1]
}

def javascriptCode = '''
<script>
function getSelectedValues() {
    var selectedValues = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            selectedValues.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('selectedValues').value = selectedValues.join(',');
}
</script>
'''
def checkboxesHTML = "<table>"
def count = 0
givenValues.each { value ->
    if (count % 5 == 0) {
        checkboxesHTML += "<tr>"
    }
    checkboxesHTML += "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='${value}' onclick='getSelectedValues()'>${value}</td>"
    count++
    if (count % 5 == 0) {
        checkboxesHTML += "</tr>"
    }
}
checkboxesHTML += "</table>"
return javascriptCode + checkboxesHTML + '''
<input type='hidden' id='selectedValues' name='value'>
'''



If I reference Referenced parameters(ENV) in groovy script, the function getSelectedValues cannot be found in the generated html,the error is Uncaught ReferenceError: getSelectedValues is not defined
    if ENV.equals("test"){
        givenValues = [1]
    }

If getSelectedValues is inline,it works too
    checkboxesHTML += "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='${value}' onclick='var selectedValues = []; var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(\"checkbox\"); for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { if (checkboxes[i].checked) { selectedValues.push(checkboxes[i].value); } } document.getElementById(\"selectedValues\").value = selectedValues.join(\",\");'>${value}</td>"

